# In VBA how do I write a script to copy a button from one worksheet to a worksheet in a different note book(without recording macros and using .select)

Tags: excel, vba

The code below copies a button from one sheet to another sheet in a different workbook. The end result is a runtime error '1004': The item with the specified name wasn't found. Also the button is pasted into the sheet that was intended but with additional, arbitrary buttons. EX. A button labeled: Button 9 and Button 8 are pasted into the destination sheet, and what's weird is that their "names" when I click on them are Button 4 and Button 8 respectively which makes no sense to me. I've read to avoid using select, but I haven't found a good way to do this.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 4")).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Copy Between Worksheets.xlsm").Activate
Range("E12").Select
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(196.5, 123.5, 89.5, 28).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 3")).Select
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Sample()
    Dim wbThis As Workbook, wbThat As Workbook
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet, wsThat As Worksheet
    Dim shpThis As Shape, shpThat As Shape
    
    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsThis = wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set shpThis = wsThis.Shapes("Button 4")
    
    Set wbThat = Workbooks("Copy Between Worksheets.xlsm")
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set wsThat = wbThat.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    '~~> Copy the shape
    shpThis.Copy
    
    '~~> Paste it in the relevant sheet
    wsThat.PasteSpecial Format:="Microsoft Office Drawing Object", _
                        Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                       
    '~~> The last shape that you pasted is what you want
    Set shpThat = wsThat.Shapes(wsThis.Shapes.Count)
    
    With shpThat
        '
        ' ~~> Do what you want with the shape here
        '
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note**: When you run the code twice, you will end up with a second button which also has the same name. This is the default beaviour unfortunately and hence use the method `Set shpThat = wsThat.Shapes(wsThis.Shapes.Count)` instead of working with names. It is also a good idea to give it a unique name after you paste it. For example `shpThat.Name = "WhatEverName"`

**EDIT**

To deselect the shape add this at the end of the code

```
wsThat.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
```

Comment: That worked! The only thing is that when the button is pasted, it is default selected and you can still move it around. I guess that's cus there no range specified for the paste. When I do specify a range, it ends up pasting as a picture. Any idea how to solve that?

EX.     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 1").Shapes("Button 10").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 2").Range("I10").PasteSpecial Format:="Microsoft Office Drawing Object", _
                        Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

Comment: My comment above looks hard to read since it doesn't let me format, but I can make another post

Comment: I have updated the post, you may have to refresh it to see it